# Symfony2 Form classes ContextErrorException

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form class that extends AbstractType. My code is as follows...

1. Fetch FormBuilder and create one

   ```
   $formFactory = $this->container->get('form.factory');
   $builder = $formFactory->createBuilder('form', new MyEntity(), array());
   ```
2. Call the `create()` method of the FormBuilder

   ```
    $form = $builder->create(new MyType());
   ```

What am I doing wrong? The error is as follows...

```
     ContextErrorException: Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in C:\xampp\htdocs\icooicoo\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata.php line 289
```

Also, documentation says that i should pass the `$task` variable to the `create()` method which is Task entity object but that method has to accept FormTypeInterface variable.

Comment: What's `$task` variable? Your codes suggest only MyEntity and MyType? Which one should be substituted for $task?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to create form builder, if you already have a `FormType`. You can simply call it as follows:

```
$formFactory = $this->container->get('form.factory');
$form = $formFactory->create( new MyType(), new MyEntity() );
```

The second issue with your error may be solved by this above. If it isn't, then it must be related to some validation markup. Please paste in your `Entity` `Annotation` related to validation (if you are using this method), or paste in the YML file you are using for Validation. Or anything else you think is related to Validation.

***Explanation of errors in your code***

- The first parameter in `CreateBuilder` is the $data (entity, $task, etc.)
- when calling `$builder->create`, then the first parameter is the type of the form, the second is the underlying $data